# Disable double click selection in a JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing, double-click, caret, jtextcomponent

Generally when you double click in a text component, the entire word is selected.

I would like to disable selection of this single word but still maintain the ability to click and drag to select it.

Example: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

When I click and drag from the beginning of "The" to the end of "dog," the text is selected. However, when I double click "brown," "brown" is not selected and a different action can be preformed.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: there are two correct ways how to determine double_click, please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @mKorbel sorry about that, I updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where edit is JTextComponent instance

```
DefaultCaret c=new DefaultCaret() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int nclicks = SwingUtilities2.getAdjustedClickCount(getComponent(), e);
        if (! e.isConsumed() &&
                SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) &&
                nclicks == 2
                && SwingUtilities2.canEventAccessSystemClipboard(e)) {
            return;
        }

        super.mouseClicked(e);
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int nclicks = SwingUtilities2.getAdjustedClickCount(getComponent(), e);
        if (! e.isConsumed() &&
                SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) &&
                nclicks == 2
                && SwingUtilities2.canEventAccessSystemClipboard(e)) {
            return;
        }
        super.mousePressed(e);
    }
};
c.setBlinkRate(edit.getCaret().getBlinkRate());
edit.setCaret(c);
```

Comment: great, excelent knowledge, you're King_of_JTextComponents, only +1

Comment: Thank you. After implementing editor like MS Word based on java/swings plenty of similar problems already have solutions.

Comment: I tried implementing this code but SwingUtilities2 could not be found. I am using jre1.6.0_05. I looked online for SwingUtilities2 and most posts suggest not depend on it. Are there any other solutions or workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: I just took the code from DefaultCaret source. You can use another way to get click count.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can register your own `MouseListener` or `MouseAdapter` and check the click count (i.e. [`getClickCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29)) of the `MouseEvent`. If it's equal to `2`, *swallow* the event, otherwise delegate the event handling to the superclass (e.g. `super.mouseClicked(...)`).

Comment: With "swallow" `event.consume()` is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that is to replace the selectWord action by an action that does nothing:

```
    textComponent.getActionMap().put(DefaultEditorKit.selectWordAction, 
            new TextAction(DefaultEditorKit.selectWordAction) {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // DO NOTHING
                }
            });
```

You can also use this technic to change the behaviour of the selectWord action if your definition of a word is different than the default Swing one.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement the double-click like this:

```
setCaretPosition(0);
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#select%28int,%20int%29): This points to the deprecating method `select(int,int)` which is a delegate call to `setCaretPosition` and then `moveCaretPosition`

Answer (score 0):

@Loic Your answer worked for me.
However, I still wanted to have the word selection enabled if a certain condition is fulfilled. Here is how I did it:

```
Action defaultSelectWordAction = textComponent.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.selectWordAction);

textComponent.getActionMap().put(DefaultEditorKit.selectWordAction, new TextAction(DefaultEditorKit.selectWordAction) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (conditionFulfilled()) {
                defaultSelectWordAction.actionPerformed(e);
            } else {
                // DO NOTHING
            }
        }
    });
```